# .rss file to deploy report

Tags: deployment, reporting-services, tfs

Is there a way to deploy .rdl files in structured folders that are not already on a report server? The goal is to deploy the structure from windows explorer to the target report server, which has the same structure.

I recently read this article and code, which deploys from server to server.

https://azuresql.codeplex.com/releases/view/115207

We are trying to create a build environment where the deployment of rdl files comes directly from our source control, and would like to use a script that has been as widely used as the one in the link provided.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SQL Server install folder there is an executable called rs.exe. You can use this, passing it an .RSS file that contains the configuration that you want to deploy. You can then bulk deploy from your folder to Reporting Services.

> [RS.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx)

If you have the source .rdl files in TFS you can use Team Build to process and create the .RSS and likely a zip package. You can then have it deployed by Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 through a specified release pipeline that pushed it from Dev->QA->Prod.

You can get information on how from [Professional Application Lifecycle Management with Visual Studio 2013](http://nkdalm.net/ProALMwithVS13).

Comment: note that in the question, the link provided is a .RSS which contains server to server deployment. The question was for file to server deployment. Is this possible with Visual Studio 2010 or 2012?

Comment: Its possible through passing your .RSS filt to rs.exe. This is a command line call and you can do it form nay IDE... you can't do server to server deployment. What would you deploy server to server rather than source to server? That seams to be a little...rudimentary...